# How to mathematically formulate the surface of a spring?

Tags: surfaces

I would like to mathematically map the surface of a cylinder constructed like a coil pot (or compressed spring), where the surface area and height of the pot is a function of the length of the coil, and the length of the coil is a function of time. The cylinder is infinitely long. Is there an existing way to do this?

Comment: Formulate the center of the coil as a curvature and than the surface of the points as circles around this center. You will need to specify a plane that is perpendicular to the center curve, in a parametric way and the surface will be all the parametric solutions of the points radius R (distance from the center curve), around the center curve.

Answer (score 2):

Axis-symmetric surface of torus can be shear deformed by adding a torsion term to $z-$ coordinate of a circular symmetric torus as $c \cdot\theta$.

$$ (x,y,z)= [ (a+ b \cos \phi ) \cos\theta,\,(a+ b \cos\phi )\sin\theta ,\, b \sin \phi + c \cdot \theta\,] $$

$a$ is spring radius, $b$ is coil radius,  $ c $ is torsional radius of curvature.

The above is written with respect to $\theta$. To convert to arc length$ s$ of coil middle line, use:

$$ \dfrac{d \theta}{ds} = \sin \alpha/ a, \tan \alpha = a/c $$

[image: Coil surface]